# Сохранение данных из DataGrid в XML

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, datagrid

Имеется таблица:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DisciplineDataGrid" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Студент" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding StudentInfo}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

В таблице также программно создаются столбцы

```
void DisciplineButtonAddColumnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridCheckBoxColumn NewColumn = new DataGridCheckBoxColumn();
        NewColumn.Header = DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString();

        DisciplineControl.DisciplineDataGrid.Columns.Add(NewColumn);

        DisciplineControl.DisciplineButtonAddColumn.IsEnabled = false;

        // Добавление столбца с ChexBox
        // Header столбца - DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();

        // DisciplineControl
    }
```

Далее в определенный момент DataGrid со всеми изменениями нужно сохранить в xml файл. 
Каким образом можно это сделать?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Король вам ответил абсолютно правильно. Если непонятно, каким образом сохранять коллекцию в XML, то погуглите про сериализацию и десериализацию.
Если в кратце, то вы должны указать для класса со списком студентов атрибут Serializable:

```
[Serializable]
public class StudentsList
{
   public List<Student> Students;
}
```

Сохранение (сереализация) в XML:

```
XmlSerializer formatter = new XmlSerializer(typeof(StudentsList));
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
    formatter.Serialize(fs, dashboard);
}
```

Выгрузка данных (десереализация):

```
var formatter = new XmlSerializer(typeof(StudentsList));
using (var fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
     var deserealizedStudentsList = (StudentsList)formatter.Deserialize(fs);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Правильно будет забайндить DataGrid на св-во View-модели `ObservableCollection<StudentInfo>`, а кнопку добавления студента на `ICommand`.

```
   <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding StudentInfos}" CanUserAddRows="True">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Студент" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
   </DataGrid>
.
.
.
 <Button Content="Добавить студента" Command="{Binding AddNewStudentCommand}"></Button>
```

Тогда по команде во ViewModel добавляете нового студента в коллекцию, а при сохранении сохраняете её в xml.